# Trying to open a workbook using a textbox and listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I need to open a specified workbook using a text box entry and using a list command to open it.
I used a cell value before and it worked but I would like to use a textbox value to make it easier for the operator.
So when I click on the listbox value it takes the textbox value then finds the workbook and opens it
I`ve also asked Mr. Excel see below

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/opening-workbook-from-user-form.1161913/

```
        Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Object)
        
        If Target.Me.Jobcard_Demands = ("Open Old JobCard") Then
        Me.Old_JobCard_No.Value
        End If
        
        End Sub
        
        Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Object)
        
        Dim PID As Double
        Dim strRootPath As String
        
        Dim objFile As Scripting.File
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim myfilename As String
        Dim Test As String
        
        Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
        
        If Target.Me.Jobcard_Demands = ("Open Old JobCard") Then
        
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\TGS-SRV01\Share\ShopFloor\PRODUCTION\JOB CARDS\1 - ARCHIVED JOB CARDS\" & Int((ActiveSheet.Range("C1") - 1) / 50) * 50 + 1 & "-" & Int((ActiveSheet.Range("C1") - 1) / 50 + 1) * 50 & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("C1"))
        
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 5) = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("C1")) And Right(objFile.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
        
        myfilename = objFile.Path
        
        End If
        
        Next objFile
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)
        
        End If
        
        End Sub
        
        
        Private Sub JobCardOpen(ByVal Target As Object)
        
        Dim objFile As Scripting.File
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim myfilename As String
        
        Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
        
        If Target.Me.Jobcard_Demands = ("Open Old JobCard") Then
        
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\TGS-SRV01\Share\ShopFloor\PRODUCTION\JOB CARDS\1 - ARCHIVED JOB CARDS\" & Int((ActiveSheet.Range("C1") - 1) / 50) * 50 + 1 & "-" & Int((ActiveSheet.Range("C1") - 1) / 50 + 1) * 50 & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("C1"))
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 5) = ActiveSheet.Range("C1") Then
        
        myfilename = objFile.Path & objFile.Name
        
        End If
        
        Next objFile
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)
        End Sub
```

Comment: Please can somebody help

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are using the Worksheet_Change and Worksheet_SelectionChange events for, I would suggest using a button to trigger the event and an InputBox for the user to enter the number.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub JobCardOpen() ' assign to button

   Dim wb As Workbook, jobno As Long
   jobno = InputBox("Enter Job No")
   Set wb = OpenJobCard(jobno)
   ' process wb
   If wb Is Nothing Then
   Else
      MsgBox wb.Name & " workbook is open", vbInformation
      wb.Close
   End If
   
End Sub

Function OpenJobCard(jobno As Long) As Workbook

    Const ROOT = "\\TGS-SRV01\Share\ShopFloor\PRODUCTION\JOB CARDS\1 - ARCHIVED JOB CARDS\"
    
    Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile
    Dim n As Long, sFolderName As String, bFound As Boolean
    
    n = 50 * Int((jobno - 1) / 50)
    sFolderName = ROOT & CStr(n + 1) & "-" & CStr(n + 50) & "\" & CStr(jobno)
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' check folder exists
    If objFSO.FolderExists(sFolderName) Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFolderName)
    Else
        MsgBox sFolderName & "\ not found", vbCritical, "Folder not found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    bFound = False
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.Name Like CStr(jobno) & "*.xlsm" Then
            Set OpenJobCard = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
            bFound = True
        End If
    Next objFile
            
    If bFound = False Then
        MsgBox "No File found in " & sFolderName, vbCritical, "File not found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, one issue every time I use the code it blanks out the list box.

Comment: Please don`t worry I used a command button instead. Again thank you for your effort & help

Comment: Sorry about this but even when they are Command buttoned they still empty the Listbox? Listbox is called Jobcard Demands

Comment: @user144 I can't help without seeing a lot more of your code but my guess is that in opening another workbook you are triggering one of your change events.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by Triggering one of your change events?

Comment: @user123 Any subs that end in the word change like Worksheet_change. How much other code do you have in the workbook ?

Comment: Sorry, I got muddled this is the code shown above which empties the Listbox. Not the one you did?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228888/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-user14435479).